# Strange LinearLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(...) behavior

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder, linearlayoutmanager

I have a `RecyclerView` with an `Adapter` which holds two different kinds of views. The first view has a slightly bigger width and height than the following views.

When starting the activity which contains the `RecyclerView`, I want to scroll to a certain position in the `Adapter`. I do this by calling `scrollToPositionWithOffset(position, offset)` on the `LinearLayoutManager` which is connected to the `RecyclerView`.

The following code roughly describes the setup (nothing unusual). The activity which contains the `RecyclerView` calls `Timeline.scrollTo(position)`.
Please bear with me for posting Scala code.

Activity which holds the `RecyclerView`

```
class Activity extends [...] {

    lazy val timeline = findView( TR.layout_screen_transaction_timeline )

    override def onCreate( state: Option[Bundle] ) = {
        super.onCreate( state )

        setContentView( R.layout.screen_transaction_timeline )

        [...]

        timeline.setAdapter( adapter )

        if ( state.isEmpty ) {
            focus.foreach { position ⇒
                new Handler().post { () ⇒
                    timeline.scrollTo( position )
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

RecyclerView with LinearLayoutManager

```
class Timeline( attributes: AttributeSet = null, style: Int = 0 )( implicit context: Context )
    extends RecyclerView( context, attributes, style ) {
    [...]

    setHasFixedSize( true )
    setLayoutManager( layoutManager )

    def scrollTo( position: Int ) = {
        layoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset( position, 0 )
    }

    object layoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager( context, VERTICAL, false )
}
```

Adapter

```
object adapter extends Adapter[Holder] {
    override def getItemCount = tour.shipments.length + 1

    override def onBindViewHolder( holder: Holder, position: Int ) = holder.view match {
        case collection: widget.transaction.timeline.Header ⇒
            collection.set( tour.collection, tour, tour.state == Tour.State.New )
        case waypoint: widget.transaction.timeline.Waypoint ⇒
            waypoint.set( position, tour.shipments( position - 1 ), focus.contains( position ) )
    }

    override def onCreateViewHolder( parent: ViewGroup, kind: Int ) = Holder {
        val view = kind match {
            case 0 ⇒ new widget.transaction.timeline.Header()
            case 1 ⇒ new widget.transaction.timeline.Waypoint()
        }

        view.setLayoutParams( new RecyclerView.LayoutParams( MATCH_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT ) )
        view
    }

    override def getItemViewType( position: Int ) = position match {
        case 0 ⇒ 0
        case _ ⇒ 1
    }
}
```

Everything works fine except when I want to scroll to the last position.
In that case the `LinearLayoutManager` sometimes scrolls to the position correctly and sometimes in a way which is slightly off.

Update: I just found out that removing the `ActionBar` in the activity which holds the `RecyclerView` resolves this issue. However I need an `ActionBar`...

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using [scrollToPosition](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#scrollToPosition(int)) on the recyclerview rather than directly calling the linearlayout implementation?

Comment: Yes, I did. Did not work.